# How to access asp.net hosted in a IIS from a remote server?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have published my asp.net core test application through visual studio in IIS hosted from a  remote server. I was able to published the site successfully  and can access it from the remote server through 'http://aspcore.local:90/'. how can i access it from my local machine? i've tried using the remote server ip address e.g http://192.168.20.1:90 getting refused to connect..[image]

Comment: What bindings did you configure in IIS?

Comment: Hi mason,  in my visual studio applicationhost.config file i added this binding which is the asp site port no and server ip address. not sure if this is correct.
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":90:192.168.20.27" /> ip is pingable 
Reply from 192.168.20.27......

Comment: Anything you set on your local machine's `applicationHost.config` won't affect the remote server.  You need to know the site bindings on that remote machine and adjust them accordingly. Something basic on bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html